# Арифметические операторы (задать шаг в одну единицу по клику)

Tags: java, android

Имеется вот такое view [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача проста- по клику плюсовать или минусовать в одну единицу значение, и выводить в text_view(на картинке). Имеется такой код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageView plus;
ImageView minus;
TextView tvResult;
String oper = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    plus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    minus= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    minus.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 1;
    int result = 0;
    // читаем TextView и заполняем переменные числами
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(tvResult.getText().toString());
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.plus:
            oper = "+";
            result = num1 + num2;
            break;
}
    // формируем строку вывода
    tvResult.setText(num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + result);
}
}
```

Разметка

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvResult"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/plus"
    android:text="1">
</TextView>
```

На вывод идет  1+1=2, а на второй клик приложение вырубается вовсе, помогите разобраться плз)

Готовый код по решению этого вопроса ниже.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{


ImageView plus;
ImageView minus;
TextView tvResult;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    plus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    minus= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    minus.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int num1;
    int num2 = 1;
    int result = 0;
    // читаем TextView и заполняем переменные числами
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(tvResult.getText().toString());
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.plus:
            result = num1 + num2;
    }
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.minus:
            result = num1 - num2;
            if (num1==1){
                return;
            }
    }
    // формируем строку вывода
    tvResult.setText( String.valueOf(result) );

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При втором нажатии на кнопку у вас в текстовом поле резутат вот этого лежит в виде строки:

> num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + result

В итоге, когда вы пытаетесь вызвать

> num1 = Integer.parseInt(tvResult.getText().toString());

вы получаете `NumberFormatException`, из-за того, что подобную строку нельзя преобразовать в число.

Очевидно, что вам надо перенести переменную result в активити и именно от неё отталкиваться при вычислениях, а не от текста в текстовом поле

Comment: но задача как раз состоит в том, чтобы менялось число именно  в textview, вытягивало оттуда значение и выводило с помощью tvResult.setText в это же textview, или для чисел совершенно другой способ? я загуглил пример http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/54-urok-19-pishem-prostoj-kalkuljator так там парсят edittext (Float.parseFloat(etNum1.getText().toString());) но не textview, не думал, что есть такая критическая разница.   Может как-то обойтись без парсинга? Тут особо и вычислять не нужно ничего, но я завис)

Comment: @Romikromikromik, у вас в TetxView после первого нажатия не число, но строка вида "1+1=2" - такое нельзя преобразовать в число. Для простоты выводите в текстовое поле не это, а только значение `result` - тогда всё будет работать.

Comment: Вывести  tvResult.setText( result) не удается и выдает ошибку, но если сделать со скобками  tvResult.setText( " " + result), то норм, но в свою очередь такую строку в цифровое значение уже, как Вы говорили не преобразуешь и опять ошибка на следующем шаге.

Comment: @Romikromikromik, Преобразуйте число в строку так: `tvResult.setText( String.valueof(result));`

Comment: Спасибо!   готовый код кинул в тело письма, может кому то будет нужно.